# How to register derived instance of DbContext?

Tags: asp.net-core, clean-architecture, ef-core-5.0

I am trying to do POC using [Clean Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures) as discussed here, using EF Core 5. In clean architecture the Infrastructure concern like database are separated in Infrastructure layer and then domain services use repository pattern to access database.

However, [In EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

> A DbContext instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and
> Repository patterns such that it can be used to query from a database
> and group together changes that will then be written back to the store
> as a unit. DbContext is conceptually similar to ObjectContext.

So I do not want to use again extra abstraction layer of Repository pattern as discussed in the clean the architecture. I would like to use `DbContext` directly in domain services.

However, The derived DbContext, ie. `MyDbContext` needs to reside in `Infrastructure` layer

**ApplicationCore Layer**

- Entities will be in ApplicationCore layer.
- References `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` (NOT `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`)
- Application Core does not need to know what database application is using.

  ```
  //I am injecting DbContext not MyDbContext

  public class UserService : IUserService
  {
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public UserService(DbContext dbContext)       
    {
       _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUser(string loginName)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<User>()                
            .Where(x => x.LoginName == loginName && x.IsActive)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
  ```

  }

**Infrastructure Layer**

- References `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

  ```
    public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
       public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext > options) : 
        base(options)
       {
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
       }
    }
  ```

Then in Startup.cs register DbContext

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

However during runtime when try to resolve UserService it throw exception `Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'`. Because DI does not know how to resolve `DbContext`

How do I register Scoped instance of `MyDbContext` as `DbContext`? *(or is the design pattern I am trying to use is wrong?)*

Comment: Why are you using `DbContext` and `Set<>()` in the first place? That's the bug. `DbContext` is the base class of *every* context class. The DI middleware can't guess which one of the potentially dozens of registered DbContext-derived classes to use

Comment: A DbContext is actually a Unit-of-Work handling the entities of a specific use case/scenario/bounded context. A DbSet<T> is actually a repository for a specific entity. It makes little sense to try to use the base class DbContext only to try to get the *specialized* entities defined and configured in the derived class. PS: In EF Core 5 and earlier the DbSet<T> properties cause their metadata to be cached. With `.Set<T>()`, the metadata is rebuilt every time

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to inject dbcontext since it  doesn' t have any concrete data at all. you can use new as well.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my application has only one database so one type of `DbContext`. I am not sure what do you mean by `potentially dozens of registered DbContext-derived classes`. But I do agree that application with multiple databases, cant determine which DbContext to use

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  The referenced Clean Architecture use `dbConext.Set<T>()` in the Repository https://github.com/ardalis/Specification/blob/main/Specification.EntityFrameworkCore/src/Ardalis.Specification.EntityFrameworkCore/RepositoryBaseOfT.cs
I use the same, except directly in Domain Service.

Comment: and also `DbSet<TEntity> objects are usually obtained from a DbSet<TEntity> property on a derived DbContext or from the Set<TEntity>() method.`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: And yet you have a problem. Because DI doesn't work that way. There's no way a human could guess what DbContext-derived class you want just by looking at that class. How could the DI container, which only works based on types, do better? The links and the quote don't contradict what I said.

Answer (score 0):

So changing the registration like below it worked

```
        services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyDbContext>((sp) =>
        {
            var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                                .UseSqlServer(connection)
                                .Options;
            return new MyDbContext(contextOptions);
        });
```

However, I do agree that injecting base `DbContext` will have issue if your application is dealing with multiple databases.